# Nginx lua modify html response after proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, lua

What I'm trying to do for a PoC and is to add a href to web pages coming from a dynamic backend server.  Adding the href is easy using "subs_filter", but I need to use information embedded within the response to construct the href.

Is it possible to use LUA to process the response from proxy_pass, modify it and return to requester (client)?

Any and all suggestions welcome.

Below is the code I'm looking at, now I understand Lua better and how nginx uses it I see that 'body_filter' is the correct way to.  However the code seems simple enough but i can't get the regex to work.

Further background, I'm trying to parse the returned proxy_pass response, parse it for a start and end time, then construct a JS script url placed into the head.

Example response that I want to regex against.

```
Informações Adicionais
   Horário de início: 08H50
   Horário de término: 09H14
```

The code from within the 'location {}'

```
body_filter_by_lua '
        -- my regex which is validate but doesn't seem to be within LUAJIT
        --local from, to, err = ngx.re.find(ngx.arg[1], "(.início: *\d{2}H\d{2})", "jo")
        local from, to, err = ngx.re.find(ngx.arg[1], "início", "jo")

        replacestr = string.sub(ngx.arg[1], to, 5)

        replaceme = "<script></script></head>"
        ngx.arg[1] = ngx.re.sub(ngx.arg[1],"</head>", replaceme)
    ';
```

Changing "início" to "head" for example works, so I'm assuming it is the accented char but I'm unable to find confirmation of this.

Changing "início" to "*\d{2}H\d{2}" fails, with "body_filter_by_lua:5: invalid escape sequence near '"*'"

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What research have you done?

Comment: I have been trying to use 'content_by_lua', also  'ngx.location.capture' and other methods.  I finally found possibly what I am looking for, which is to use 'body_filter_by_lua' and setting 'ngx.header.content_length = nil'.

Comment: Thanks Andy, this information helps others who can assist in general.  That's great that you think you may have found a solution.  If you have it, consider posting it as an `answer` below to yourself just in case others might run into the same problem down the track.  You should be able to `mark` it as _an answer_ too. Thanks buddy

Comment: @User52784246 Thanks.  I have made progress now I understand nginx use of Lua better but I'm not quite there.  I have improved my question.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what I mentioned in the comments regarding 'nix.header.content_length' and importantly nginx and lua require double escaping see: [lua-nginx-module special pcre sequences](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#special-pcre-sequences) for more details.

The accented chars needed the flag 'u' adding to 'jo' of the 'ngx.re.find'

Answer (score 0):

user "body_filter_by_lua_file"

Equivalent to body_filter_by_lua, except that the file specified by  contains the Lua code, or, as from the v0.5.0rc32 release, the Lua/LuaJIT bytecode to be executed.

When a relative path like foo/bar.lua is given, they will be turned into the absolute path relative to the server prefix path determined by the -p PATH command-line option while starting the Nginx server.

This directive was first introduced in the v0.5.0rc32 release.